# CppUtest shared resources between tests, undefined reference

Tags: c++, tdd, cpputest

This is a simple question I believe... I want the variable `virtualLeds` to be shared between all the tests in the test group `LedDriverTests`, this is the code:

```
#include "CppUTest/TestHarness.h"
#include <stdint.h>

extern "C"
{
    #include "led_driver.h"
}

TEST_GROUP(LedDriverTests)
{
    static uint16_t virtualLeds;

    void setup()
    {
    }

    void teardown()
    {
    }

    void expect(void)
    {
    }

    void given(void)
    {
    }
};

TEST(LedDriverTests, AllOffAtInitialization)
{
    // Set all the bits to 1, the LEDs are turned ON by hardware.
    virtualLeds = 0xFFFF;
    led_driver_create(&virtualLeds);
    LONGS_EQUAL(0x0000, virtualLeds);
}

TEST(LedDriverTests, TurnOnLedOne)
{
    led_driver_turn_on(1);
    LONGS_EQUAL(0x0001, virtualLeds);
}

TEST(LedDriverTests, TurnOffLedOne)
{
    led_driver_turn_on(1);
    led_driver_turn_off(1);
    LONGS_EQUAL(0x0000, virtualLeds);
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `TEST_GROUP_CppUTestGroupLedDriverTests::virtualLeds'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any good reason to share state between tests here.  Sharing state between tests (as opposed to fresh state for each test) results in order dependencies between tests and [fragile tests](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fragile%20Test.html) that can intermittently fail as the code changes.  Your best option is to use a [fresh fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fresh%20Fixture.html) for each test case.

Answer (score 1):

`TEST_GROUP` macro creates a [struct](https://github.com/cpputest/cpputest/blob/32dd4276545dd947e166b6bc9ae646f1e2895973/include/CppUTest/UtestMacros.h) and then you create a static member in that struct. See more about [static members in struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19469639/1517864). In short that's why you're unable to access it in this way `virtualLeds = 0xFFFF;`

Looking at your code. I think what you want to do is:

```
TEST_GROUP(LedDriverTests)
{
    uint16_t virtualLeds;

    void setup()
    {
        // Set all the bits to 1, the LEDs are turned ON by hardware.
        virtualLeds = 0xFFFF;
    }

};

TEST(LedDriverTests, AllOffAtInitialization)
{
    led_driver_create(&virtualLeds);
    LONGS_EQUAL(0x0000, virtualLeds);
}

TEST(LedDriverTests, TurnOnLedOne)
{
    led_driver_turn_on(1);
    LONGS_EQUAL(0x0001, virtualLeds);
}

TEST(LedDriverTests, TurnOffLedOne)
{
    led_driver_turn_on(1);
    led_driver_turn_off(1);
    LONGS_EQUAL(0x0000, virtualLeds);
}
```

`setup()` is called before running each `TEST`

Remember that [unit tests should pass or fail independently of other tests](https://pragprog.com/magazines/2012-01/unit-tests-are-first).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a definition for the static member:

```
TEST_GROUP(LedDriverTests)
{
    static uint16_t virtualLeds;

    // ...
};

// Definition of static data
uint16_t TEST_GROUP_CppUTestGroupLedDriverTests::virtualLeds;

// ...
```