# How to assign protected static member of struct in c?

Tags: c++, struct

code is

```
struct {
  protected:
   static int labelCounter;
};
```

Comment: how would you assign the value of a protected non static member? there some difference in initialization compared to an instance method, but no (not much) difference in value assignment

Comment: I dont see what is unclear about this thread... How to initialize a static member. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469475/struct-static-member-meaning-definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

protected members can be assigned in methods that belong to the class, or any derived class.

Your static member can be initialized normally, but you have to give a name to the struct:

```
struct MyStruct { protected: static int labelCounter; };

// .cpp:
int MyStruct::labelCounter = 12;
```

Comment: Thanks that is it.

Comment: @Gangesh That is not assignment, that is initialization!  Please learn the difference.